# I just upgraded to drools 5 and the xml rules will not load

Tags: java, drools

When upgrading to drools 5, valid drools 4 xml rules do not work. Drools just throws an unhelpful null pointer exception. What can the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Drools 5 changed the namespace. Replace xmlns="http://drools.org/drools-4.0" with xmlns="http://drools.org/drools-5.0" and at least for simple rules that is all you need.

I hope that helps save someone the headache I just got dealing with this undocumented change.